# Sum By Row Dataframe R (Fastest Way!)

Tags: r, performance, dataframe, row

currently, I am using for loops for sum of rows like below

```
dat <- c(1,2,3,4)
dat1 <- c(1,2,3,4)
dat2 <-c(1,2,3,4)

df <- data.frame(dat,dat1,dat2)


sum <- NULL
for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
  i <- sum(df[i,],na.rm=T)
  sum <- rbind(sum,i)
```

what would be the fastest way to do this, keeping the structure same as my example sum

Answer (score 2):

We can use `rowSums` which would be much faster than the looping through the rows as `rowSums` is vectorized optimized for these kind of operations

```
matrix(rowSums(df, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Comment: @AlgoQuant  Just wrap with `matrix` if you want a one column `matrix`